# (Decimal)x Diffeernce betewen Decimal(x);

Tags: c++

Given a class, `Decimal`, what is the difference between the expressions `(Decimal)x` and `Decimal(x)`?

Additionally information, in case it matters : `x` is an object of type `MLBigNumVar`, another user-defined class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: @zenith How the heck did you know that?

Comment: @NeilKirk IMO the question is (almost) pretty clear: "What's the difference between function-style and C-style casts?" But of course I might just have misunderstood.

Comment: @zenith I think it is vaguely clear at best.

Comment: Depends on context, e.g. `(Decimal)x;` is very different to `Decimal(x);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Decimal` is a type name, and `x` is a value, then both are equivalent. They convert the value of `x` to the type `Decimal`. The first uses *cast notation* and the second uses *functional notation*, both of which have the same meaning.

Comment: MLBigNumVar  1e18 (one product ) is actually  --  1,000,000,000,000,000,000  ( 19 digits, more than 16 digits but with trailing or exceeding digits are zeros) – Assigned successfully to decimal.
MLBigNumVar  1e35 (another product) is actually --  100,000,000,000,000,016,384,608,344,632,472,552  ( 36 digits , more than 16 digits but trailing or exceeding digits are not zeros --  assignment to decimal results in overflow ).  This conversion with 36 digits would also had succeeded if all the trailing digits were zeros 

Is there a work around using which the conversion can be made successful?

Comment: @ShobhaPv: Without knowing what the types are (they're not standard C++ types, but something defined by your program or some library it uses) there's no way to say. But if it can't represent that value, then it can't represent that value.